# What does White space mean when you mount ISO

Tags: rhel, repository

I mounted redhat dvd media and I named in redhat.iso. And when i mounted it and did

> ls

it showed /media/RHEL-**5.6 i386 DVD**. What does this space mean between 5.6 and i386 and DVD.

Because Im creating a DVD based Repository which i will use to Upgrade the Redhat linux.

Im asking this because I have to assign this path in Baserul=file:///Absolute/Path to run

> yum upgrade

command which will upgrade redhat 5.5 to 5.6. And when assign it like this 
baseurl=file:////media/RHEL-5.6 i386 DVD

it give me error that i can only use https, ftp or URL not " "

## df -h Results

[image: FS]

## Instructions entered in dvd.repo

```
[dvd.repo]
name=dvd.repo
baseurl=file:///media/RHEL_5.6\ i386\ DVD/SERVER
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

And when I omitted white space and wrote basurl like this

baseurl=file:///media/RHEL_5.6\i386\DVD/Server

and saved it and then used the command YUM CLEAN ALL 
and after that YUM LIST ALL it smashed me with this message

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using backslashes? So

```
baseurl=file:////media/RHEL-5.6\ i386\ DVD
```

This escapes the whitespaces and tells RPM that these are part of the value for baseurl.

Comment: Yes dear I did this but it is saying the same thing. Well I took the screenshot and uploaded it. Tell me how can i add the path against baseurl

Comment: What about replacing the spaces with %20? It seams like RPM transforms “\ ” to “\\”; and allow URL encoded characters (0x20 is the ASCII code of a whitespace)